# Where to place setup.py file to make Flask project installable?

Tags: flask, setup.py

I'm currently following tutorial on flask projects from palletprojects. 
I'm trying to understand what should be the location of setup.py file, as described on this link 
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/install/

Summary of the code can be found on the following link

[Installing Flask project can't open setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058876/installing-flask-project-cant-open-setup-py)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your current directory structure.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it ! Thank you :)